# Add function to custom menu

Tags: menus

I am am trying to add a function to my custom menu. The menu works, but I have no idea on how to get the `custom_execute_shortcode()` function to work inside the `add_profile_link_to_nav()` function.

Any help appreciated.

```
//--Nav Menu
function add_profile_link_to_nav(){ 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> 

<ul> 
         <li class="menu-item"id="one"> <a href="http://example.com/members/">All  Members</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"> 

function custom_execute_shortcode() {
$myfunction= '[Shortcode]';
$myfunction_parsed = do_shortcode($myfunction);
echo $myfunction_parsed;
}


            <li class="menu-item"> </li>
   </ul> 
</li>
<!--end menu--->
<?php 
} 
}
add_action( "wp_nav_items","add_profile_link_to_nav" );
```

Thanks, Tim .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, don't bundle the function inside.  Instead, break it out like this:

```
//--Nav Menu
function add_profile_link_to_nav(){ 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> 

<ul> 
    <li class="menu-item"id="one"> <a href="http://example.com/members/">All  Members</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"> 
            <?php echo custom_execute_shortcode(); ?>
            <li class="menu-item"> </li>
        </ul> 
    </li>
</ul>    <!--end menu--->
    <?php } 
}
add_action( "wp_nav_items","add_profile_link_to_nav" );

function custom_execute_shortcode() {
     $myfunction= '[Shortcode]';
     $myfunction_parsed = do_shortcode($myfunction);
     return $myfunction_parsed;
}
```

Comment: Hello EAMann, thanks for the responce, I tryed as you suggested but not working.  The menu is there the drop down is there but the short code does is not executing.  The short code I am using does execute in a php widget

Comment: This might be the problem? in my header.php I am executing my "function add_profile_link_to_nav()" with <?php echo add_profile_link_to_nav(); ?>.  Would this cause a problem.  This short code with in a short code?

Comment: Yes.  You're `echo`ing a function that doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: I have continued to google this question and if I have understood correctly shortcodes only execute on pages and posts, so no shortcodes in menus!

Comment: Typically, yes.  Shortcodes only function *by default* in post/page content because that content is passed through a filter that parses all shortcodes.  But realistically, you can apply that filter to *any* content or invoke `do_shortcode()` directly from any location in your theme.